# Uitableview with same uitableview cell for two different model class

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have one uitableview controller class for which i am using a single UITableViewCell,but I am using two different model classes. In my tableview I have to show the values fetched from database using this two model classes. For one model class I can fetch the data and display it.But I cannot display the data from the second model class.
 Somebody plz help me out

Comment: I got one question for you. "What are you saying?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See a sample of my code, managing 2 types of cell (inbox or outbox), hope it will help you.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        Feedback *feedback =     [self.guideline.feedbacks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if([feedback.user_role isEqualToString:@"STORE"] || !feedback.user_role){
            ChatInboxCelliPad* icell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ChatInboxCell"];
            if(!icell){
                icell = [[ChatInboxCelliPad alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"ChatInboxCell"];
            }
            [icell setData:feedback];
            return icell;

        }
        else{
            ChatOutboxCell* ocell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ChatOutboxCell"];

            if(!ocell){
                ocell = [[ChatOutboxCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"ChatOutboxCell"];
            }
            [ocell setData:feedback];
            return ocell;

        }
}
```

Comment: I want to access two model classes using a single custom cell but not two custom cells. Can you please help me in this context.

Comment: it's not clear what are looking for, please try to update your initial question with more details&code